# Monitor python scraper programs on multiple Amazon EC2 servers with a single web interface written in Django

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, distributed-computing

I have a web-scraper (command-line scripts) written in Python that run on 4-5 Amazon-EC2 instances.

What i do is place the copy of these python scripts in these EC2 servers and run them.

So the next time when i change the program i have to do it for all the copies.

So, you can see the problem of redundancy, management and monitoring.

> So, to reduce the redundancy and for easy management , I want to place the code in a separate server from which it can be executed on other EC2 servers  and also monitor theses python programs, and logs created them through a Django/Web interface situated in this server.

Comment: I googled and found out fabric-python may help.

Comment: Here http://www.slideshare.net/ffunction/fabric-cuisine-and-watchdog-for-server-administration-in-python
But i am still not sure if this is the right approach

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two issues you're dealing with:

- monitoring of execution of the scraping tasks
- deployment of code to multiple servers

and each of them requires a different solution.

In general I would recommend using task queue for this kind of assignment (I have tried and was very pleased with [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) running on Amazon EC2).

One advantage of the task queue is that it abstracts the definition of the task from the worker which actually performs it. So you send the tasks to the queue, and then a variable number of workers (servers with multiple workers) process those tasks by asking for them one at a time. Each worker if it's idle will connect to the queue and ask for some work. If it receives it (a task) it will start processing it. Then it might send the results back and it will ask for another task and so on.

This means that a number of workers can change over time and they will process the tasks from the queue automatically until there are no more tasks to process. The use case for this is **using Amazon's Spot instances which will greatly reduce the cost**. Just send your tasks to the queue, create X spot requests and see the servers processing your tasks. You don't really need to care about the servers going up and down at any moment because the price went above your bid. That's nice, isn't it ?

Now, this implicitly takes care of monitoring - because celery has tools for monitoring the queue and processing, it can even be integrated with django using [django-celery](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery).

When it comes to deployment of code to multiple servers, Celery doesn't support that. The reasons behind this are of different nature, see e.g. [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/celery-users/tBJs3btilPk). One of them might be that it's just difficult to implement.

I think it's possible to live without it, but if you really care, I think there's a relatively simple DIY solution. Put your code under VCS (I recommend [Git](http://git-scm.com/)) and check for updates on a regular basis. If there's an update, run a bash script which will kill your workers, make all the updates and start the workers again so that they can process more tasks. Given Celerys ability to handle failure this should work just fine.